# Need Help to replace currentTarget javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

i need some help with my Javascript, The problem is that my JavaScript code is not working properly on Internet explorer 8 as well as Internet explorer 7, it is giving error saying that currentTarget cannot be supported on Internet explorer 8 / 7. so i need some help to get this thing fixed, and working on Internet explorer 8 / 7.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/63/)

---

```
var dataSource = ({
    "Pen": ({
        "Cello": ({
            "C2": ({}),
            "C1": ({})
        }),
            "Parker": ({
            "P2": ({}),
            "P1": ({})
        })
    })
});
 var traverseObject = function (obj) {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li;

        for (var prop in obj) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
            li.onclick = function(e) {
                var classNames = e.currentTarget.className;
                if (classNames.indexOf("hidden") == -1) {
                    e.currentTarget.className += "hidden";
                } else {
                    e.currentTarget.className = e.currentTarget.className.replace("hidden", "");
                }
                e.stopPropagation();
            }

            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Object.keys(obj[prop]).length) {
                console.log(Object.keys(obj[prop]).length + "  " + Object.keys(obj[prop]));
                li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[prop]));
            } else {
                li.className += "leaf";
            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    };


window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("dvList1").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));
    document.getElementById("dvList2").appendChild(sortedObject(dataSource));
}
```

---

Thank you

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery when you don't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in event handlers instead of `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: can you show me an example how to use this keyword??

Comment: Simply replace every occurrence of `e.currentTarget` with `this`.

Comment: But e.stopPropagation(); is causing an error on IE 8 and 7

Comment: `return false` should do it as well. Though I don't really understand why you need it at all

Comment: if you check the fiddle it will show you what i am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you, not to fix the compatible problem, but to find some tools which already fix the compatible problem.
Here, I suggest you use JQuery to rewrite the script.

`li.onclick -> $(li).click(function(event){/*process code*/})`

Hope this helps